# What is the Best Practice or most efficient way to update custom python modules in pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, module, pythonanywhere

For PythonAnywhere:

I am currently building a project where I have to change one of my installed packages frequently (because I am adding to the package as I build out the project).  It is very manual and laborious to constantly update the package in the BASH console be reinstalling the package everytime I make a change locally.  Is there a better process for this?

Comment: To clarify:  you are developing the package on your own PC, not on PythonAnywhere?  And then you push it up to PyPI, or github (which?), and then pull it down to PythonAnywhere? (via pip or git?)

Comment: So i think you answered my question.  I can establish a connection between PA and github?  So the process could look like this: Locally make a change to the package and then update it on github.  Github will then push the package update to pythonanywhere.  Will that work?

Comment: You can certainly pull code down from github on PA, but not in an automated way (or at least not straightforwardly).  A better bet might be using PA as a git repo. will answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to use a single command from your local machine to push up some changes to PythonAnywhere, one way to go about it would be to use PythonAnywere as a git remote.  There's some details in [this post](http://blog.pythonanywhere.com/43/), but, broadly:

```
username@PythonAnywhere:~$ mkdir my_repo.git
username@PythonAnywhere:~$ cd my_repo.git
username@PythonAnywhere:~$ git init --bare
```

Then, on your PC:

```
git remote add pythonanywhere username@ssh.pythonanywhere.com:my_repo.git
```

Then you should be able to push to the bare repository on PA from your machine with a

```
git push pythonanywhere master
```

You can then use a [Git post-receive hook](http://www.sitepoint.com/git-hooks-fun-profit/) to update the package on PythonAnywhere, by whatever means you like.  One might be to have your package checked out on PythonAnywhere:

```
username@PythonAnywhere:~$ git clone my_package ./my_repo.git
```

And then the post-receive hook could be as simple as

```
cd ~/my_package && git pull
```